# How to create a fade effect in a horizontal scrolling div

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm creating a horizontally scrolling div of music albums and want to have a fade on the right hand side of the div to help convey that the list scrolls horizontally.

I've almost cracked it, but can't quite understand why I can't get it exactly the way I want.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/zauber/pen/mqXGEe) of what I have so far... The fade (red for the sake of the example) works perfectly if the position is set to `absolute` but fails when set to `fixed` - which is what I need.

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/zauber/pen/mqXGEe)

Comment: I can think of a way: Add a div on top of your "content" div and fade it's background. But the problem is that you wont be able to click anything because the 'fader' div is on top.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Attach the fade to the `.artist__media` not to `.content`.
Like this:

```
.artist__media {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;

  &:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 15px;
      pointer-events: none;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0), red 85%);
      width: 15%;
    }

  .content {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4jtnscd/1/).
Is that what you wanted?